# How to check for particular threshold for each URL?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, url

I am working on an application in which I have list of machines and for each machine I need to hit the URL which will give me response back in XML and I need to parse the XML and extract one field (dataKey is the field name) value from it for each server and then check whether that field value is matching my threshold value or not. If it is matching my threshold value three times continuously then add that server in my another List.

So if `machineA` `dataKey` field is matching my threshold value continuously for three times, then add `machineA` to my list and if my `machineB` `dataKey` field value is also matching my same thresold value continuously for three times, then add `machineB` to the same list.

And after adding the machines to the list, reset the counter and start it again.

Below is my `MachineStats` class which holds each machine information -

```
public class MachineStats {

    private String serverName;
    private String serverURL;
    private int dataKey = 0;

    public MachineStats(String serverName, String serverURL) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
        this.serverURL = serverURL;
    }

    // getters here

    public boolean isEligibleForEmail(Integer dataKeyCount, int thresholdLimit) {
        try {
            if (!TestUtils.isEmpty(dataKeyCount)) {
                if (dataKeyCount >= thresholdLimit) {
                    dataKey++;
                } else {
                    dataKey = 0;
                }

                if (dataKey > 3) {
                    dataKey = 0;
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            // log an exception
            return false;
        }
    }       
}
```

And below is the code I have in my main method which is the starting point where `serverList` holds list of machines.

```
// this holds machineA and machineB information
private static List<MachineStats> serverList = new LinkedList<MachineStats>();

while(true) {
    ServerMetricsTask task = new ServerMetricsTask(serverList, thresholdLimit);
    task.run();
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2); // sleep for 2 minutes
}
```

And below is my `ServerMetricsTask` class -

```
public class ServerMetricsTask {

    private List<MachineStats> listOfServers;
    private int thresholdLimit;

    public ServerMetricsTask(List<MachineStats> listOfServers, int thresholdLimit) {
        this.listOfServers = listOfServers;
        this.thresholdLimit = thresholdLimit;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            List<String> holder = new LinkedList<String>();

            for (MachineStats stats : listOfServers) {
                Integer dataKeyCount = TestUtils.extractKey(stats.getServerName(), stats.getServerURL());
                if (stats.isEligibleForEmail(dataKeyCount, thresholdLimit)) {
                    holder.add(stats.getServerName());
                }
            }

            if (!holder.isEmpty()) {
                // send an email with the machine name which has met the threshold
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log an exception
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

Now I have above code working fine. As of now I am only checking for one property which is `dataKey` for each server. Now I need to do the same thing for two fields for each server. One field is `dataKey` and second field is `customerKey` and these two fields will be present in the XML response for each server.

So I have a `fieldHolder` map which holds my field name for which I need to check.

Here `fieldHolder` map holds -

```
key   - field which we want to extract from the response coming from the URL.
value - is the threshold for that field which is a key.
```

Now I have modified my code like this -

```
// this holds machineA and machineB information
private static List<MachineStats> serverList = new LinkedList<MachineStats>();
private static Map<String, String> fieldHolder;

while(true) {
    ServerMetricsTask task = new ServerMetricsTask(serverList, fieldHolder);
    task.run();
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2); // sleep for 2 minutes
}
```

And below is my `ServerMetricsTask` class -

```
public class ServerMetricsTask {

    private List<MachineStats> listOfServers;
    private int thresholdLimit;

    public ServerMetricsTask(List<MachineStats> listOfServers, Map<String, String> fieldHolder) {
            this.listOfServers = listOfServers;
            this.fieldHolder = fieldHolder;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            List<String> holder = new LinkedList<String>();

            for (MachineStats stats : listOfServers) {
                //now what should I do here?
                // I guess I need to iterate fieldHolder map
            }

            if (!holder.isEmpty()) {
                // send an email with the machine name which has met the threshold
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // log an exception
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem I am facing is I don't how should I add logic so that it can extract two fields value by executing the URL after iterating `fieldHolder` map and then also check the whether those two field or either of them is meeting the threshold limit three times continuously. And if they are meeting the threshold limit three times continuously then add that machine name to the list holder.

I already know how to extract those fields values given an URL by parsing XML response.

Comment: Yes you iterate the `fieldHolder` map and change `TestUtils.extractKey(stats.getServerName(), stats.getServerURL())` to `TestUtils.extractKey(keyName, stats.getServerName(), stats.getServerURL())` so it will extract any given key. Or just pass the whole `fieldHolder` to `TestUtils.extractKey()` and let it be iterated there. It can return a similar map but containing only found keys.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko But then how I will keep the count whether my keys has met my threshold three times continuously for each server and if both the keys  or either of the keys have met the threshold, then add them to my holder list.

Comment: Oh indeed, so for each server you initialize a map of key => counter, and pass this map to extractKey, which will iterate the map and  increment counter for any found key. You then can check how many keys have valid counter. On next call you pass the same map.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko hmmm got confuse slightly. Can you provide an example how will I achieve this? Thinking I can extract those keys value from `TestUtils` class `extractKey` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, change dataKey in MachineStats to keyMap

```
public class MachineStats {
...
    private HashMap<String,int> keyMap = new HashMap<String,int>;
...
    public HashMap<String,int> getKeyMap() {
        return this.keyMap;
    }
}
```

each time you create a new MachineStats, populate its keyMap with keys needed.

```
keyMap.put("Key1", 0);
keyMap.put("Key2", 0);
// etc. I don't know how you will do it
```

Now, you need to change `TestUtils.extractKey()` so it will accept and extract any arbitrary key name. Contrary to what I said in my comments, it's better not to change its inner logic so we won't make any more changes there.

```
TestUtils.extractKey(String keyName, String serverName, string serverURL);
```

Now, ServerMetricsTask iterates the machine list, and also iterates the machine's keymap:

```
public class ServerMetricsTask {
...
            for (MachineStats stats : listOfServers) {
                //now what should I do here?
                // I guess I need to iterate fieldHolder map
                HashMap<String, int> keymap = stats.getKeyMap();
                int key_count = keymap.size();
                int valid_count = 0;
                Set<String> keys = keymap.keySet();
                for (String key : keys) {
                    int count = keymap.get(key);
                    int result = TestUtils.extractKey(key, stats.getServerName(), stats.getServerURL());
                    if (stats.isEligibleForEmail(result, thresholdLimit)) {
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        // here you can do count = 0 if you need strictly continuous appearance of the key
                    }
                    keymap.put(key, count);
                    if (count >= 3) valid_count++;
                }
                // now decide if you need all keys to be valid or just some
                if (valid_count == key_count) holder.add(stats.getServerName());
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In your suggestion, you have `keyset` in for loop `for (String key : keyset) {` what is that? or it is `keys`?